# what is the complete list of numbers that cannot be written as the sum of three powerful numbers?

Tags: number-theory

$P$ is a powerful number if it can be represented as $A^2B^3$ Where $A,B\in\Bbb{N}$. It has been proven by Heath-Brown that if $M\in\Bbb{N}$ and is sufficiently large then it can always be written as the sum of three powerful numbers. In other words the list of positive whole numbers that cannot be written as the sum of three powerful numbers is finite.

It is known that the numbers that cannot be written as the sum of three squares iff  they are of the following form $4^k(8n+7)$ where $n,k\in\Bbb{N}$. This is a super-set of numbers that cannot be written as the sum of three powerful numbers.

Here is the OIES link to the sequence https://oeis.org/A056828.

Comment: At that oeis page, it says it's conjectured the list there is complete. If anyone knew the complete list for sure, then I expect it would be there at oeis.

Comment: Jean-Marie De Koninck, Those Fascinating Numbers, page 38, states that 118 is the largest number that cannot be written as a sum of three powerful numbers (of course, he means 119). He doesn't give, or point to, a proof.

Comment: The conjecture that every $n>119$ is a sum of three powerful numbers appears at the end of a paper of Erdos, where it is attributed to Ivic. https://users.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1976-39.pdf Problems and results on number theoretic properties of consecutive integers and related questions, Proceedings of the Fifth Manitoba Conference on Numerical Mathematics (Univ. Manitoba, Winnipeg, Man., 1975), Congress. Numer. XVI , pp. 25--44, Utilitas Math., Winnipeg, Man., 1976 MR54 #10138; Zentralblatt 337.10001.